# How much power is needed to run these speakers?

Tags: amplifier, audio, speakers, sound, watts

I have couple of loudspeakers. Each is rated for:

- RMS Power 60 watts
- Power 75 watts
- vc Imp 16 Ohms

I am going to build an audio amp for those but not sure how much power is needed.

I'm concerned about burning the loudspeakers if using higher power than they can handle.

I will make the amp as simple as possible one channel only
then connect the two loudspeakers in parallel.

Comment: You forgot to say how loud they need to be, and how sensitive the speakers are to get the wanted sound pressure level and power to achieve it. Can you add that? Most likely they are loud enough even with 1 Watt. So you don't need a 60 Watt amplifier, and building such a high powered device could be dangerous if you don't know what you are doing.

Comment: I want them to be moderately loud, i dont know how to get how much sensitive they are, so a 50 watt amp would be enough for both? im thinking of 200- 300 watts considering some signal loss in the wires ...because wires lenght from amp to loudspeakers will be around 20 - 30 meters

Comment: Forget 200-300 watts - that would blow the speakers.  You won't lose any significant amount of power in 20-30 meters of wire.

Comment: connect them to an amplifier and measure the voltage at the desired volume level.

Comment: Not hyper critical. 10 or 30W may be loud enough for what you want; 100W or so is unlikely to damage them unless you are overloading it. (A 30W amp, grossly overloaded, can do more damage than a 100W one driving them properly)

Answer (score 1):

The *maximum* you need is an amplifier designed to drive an 8 ohm load with 120 watts continuous and 150 watts peak.

The load on the amplifier will be 8 ohms, given two 16 ohm speakers in parallel.

How much power you actually need depends on the space you are trying to fill with sound.  In a large hall, 120W may be appropriate.  In a small room, it will be deafening.  Comfortable listening in a small room may be only a few hundred milliwatts.